# How can I get the current entity values from loadClassMetadata?

Tags: doctrine, api-platform.com, symfony5

In my legacy database, the entities are dispatched depending on the value of an attribute. For example, the tables are called:

- `tv_rec`
- `mobi_rec`
- `blah_rec`

and the payload I receive may be something like:

```json
{
  "label": "The TV set",
  "domain": "TV",
  "price": 456.78
}
```

or

```json
{
  "label": "One mobile phone",
  "domain": "mobi",
  "price": 123.45
}
```

The Entity is defined as:

```php
// all the necessary ApiPlatform stuff
class Prod {
  private string $label;
  private float $price;
// getters and setters follow.
// Note that there is no "domain" attribute as this information is contained in the table name itself.
}
```

I need to chose the right table depending on the value of `domain` and for that, I plan to use `loadClassMetadata` but there is no access to the values of the entities.

How can I know which entity I'm currently acting on when I'm inside the `loadClassMetadata` event, in order to retrieve this value?